# Creating Code from sequence diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-generation, sequence-diagram

Is there a way to Generate Code from sequence diagram ?? All I could find is Reverse Engineeering ie..from the generated code you can obtain sequence diagram.

Is there a way to do otherway round (From the diagram to source code generation). This is already acheived for UML class diagrams.

link for the same  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx i want the same thing for sequence diagram.

Is there any third party tools generating the code from the UML Sequence diagram?? would like to know more about it..??

[And the language which i'm using for code generation is CSharp]

Can anyone please help me??
any help would be greatly appreciated..:):)

Thanks in advance:):)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was also looking for something similar and came to find [this](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-code-generation.html). [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/about-2.php) also has Various Language Support (C# Profile, Code Generator and Reverse Engineer) according to their website. Although personally I haven't used any of them and have decided not to use any automatic code generator, you may try them.