# ArgoUML Activity diagrams to code

Tags: uml, argouml

I am new to ArgoUML and I am using this software for a project, the idea of my project is to generate code using several UML models and see the results from the diagrams. I am having trouble generating code from activity diagrams and sequence diagrams. Is this feature possible and if so how?

I have three diagrams in one folder, a class diagram, a sequence diagram and an activity diagram. Class diagram code is being created but the other diagrams are not linking to this.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.24/ch07s03.html), code generation can be done currently only by the static structure (aka class diagrams).

The [previous chapter](http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.24/ch07s02.html) explains why it is more complicated to generate code from interactions (sequence diagrams) and statechart diagrams.

If you are interested in code generation from a sequence diagram, you can have a look at this question: [Creating Code from sequence diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240350/creating-code-from-sequence-diagram)